# AWS launch configuration CLI Block Devices not included

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am attempting to automate the creation process of launch configurations for my auto scaling group in aws. I am able to successfully create launch configurations using the command and they have everything set I need except for block devices. I am creating the launch configurations from an ami and I see that the ami contains 2 block device mappings but when I look at the created launch configuration the Block Devices aren't there. I am wondering why those aren't included by default as in the documentation (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/create-launch-configuration.html) it includes options to omit block devices which only makes sense if they are included by default.

I am hoping to not have to write my own script to handle this.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to add more block devices or override the AMI block device mappings?

Comment: I want the block devices defined in the AMI to be included in the Launch configuration and currently they aren't. Edited to hopefully be more clear

Comment: Only if you want to override, you have to specify that in launch configuration. Otherwise the block devices come from the AMI.

Comment: But they aren't coming from the ami even though I see them in the ami I don't see them in the launch configuration the BlockDeviceMapping array is empty

Comment: The launch configuration will not show the BlockDeviceMapping from AMI. It will show only the additional mappings or the overridden mappings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add block devices to the launch configuration or override the block device mappings (in AMI), only those mappings will be shown in describe-launch-configurations.

The block device mappings from AMIs will not be shown in describe-launch-configurations.

If you want to see the AMI's block device mappings, use `aws ec2 describe-images` or the API/SDK equivalent.

Comment: I was wondering if that was the case but I was having a hard time determining for sure. Thank you